# Invoking rest API from angularjs $http always coming to error and response and status is undefined

Tags: ajax, angularjs, rest, linkedin-api

I am trying to invoke linked rest api from my angularjs web app I am using $http for this below is the code:

```
 url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token=" + $rootScope.accessToken;
 $http({ method: 'GET', url: url, data: {} }).success(function (data, status) {


    }).error(function (data, status) {

      //the code always comes here with data ,status being null
    });
```

but if i paste the url along with my accessToken in the browser than i get the expected json response. so please tell me what am I missing in this request. thanks!

Comment: Check the request/response in Network inspector (chrome/FF), you most likely have a security error (cross domain ajax).

Comment: ok will check it but I also did $http.get() for cross browser calls still it didnt work

Comment: don't confond cross-browser and cross-domain ;)